# Is it a "deadlock"? How to avoid it in multithreading?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency

I am learning concurrency with C++ 11 currently.
I wrote a piece of code for a coursework. However, the code doesn't finish running.

My environment:

System: Windows 10

Compiler: mingw-w64x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0

Update:

I thought that "join" could end a thread. Thank to those nice guys who commented the question, I understood that "join" won't "kill" the thread. It is the function returns when the thread execution has completed. Also, the problem in my code is possibly about deadlock. I have tried some ways to solve this problem. However, it neither work.

What I have tried:
Adding

```
if(ConsumerPtr->isConsumerDead()){
            break;
        }
```

in the `void Producer::prods();` function. That doesn't work.
Later I edit some more. I added a new global variable to check if the consumer has stopped working. Also, I have added more if statement to check consumer around `void Buffer::put();`. After that, I found the code rarely worked, but failed in most time. I tried to edit the 
`std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(60));` code of sleep time after single consume/produce operation. I have enlarged 10 ms to 60 ms. Then, the code works much better. Now, it rarely fail.

I think the code doesn't finish, because there is a deadlock during running. I found a reason which could make deadlock on Wiki:a deadlock occurs when a process or thread enters a waiting state because a requested system resource is held by another waiting process, which in turn is waiting for another resource held by another waiting process. If a process is unable to change its state indefinitely because the resources requested by it are being used by another waiting process, then the system is said to be in a deadlock.

So, the question becomes: Is it really a deadlock? How to avoid deadlock? what I should edit to make my code better?

Here is the new code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>          // std::mutex, std::unique_lock
#include <condition_variable> // std::condition_variable

using namespace std;

std::mutex mu; //mutex
//std::unique_lock<mutex> locker(mu); //unique_lock
std::condition_variable cond;

std::mutex m_mutex;

int consumerRunTurns = 0;

class Buffer {
public:
Buffer():count(0) {}
void put();
int get();
bool isBufferEmpty();
bool isBufferFull();
private:
int count;
}; //end class Buffer

//Thread Class and Functions inside:
class Consumer{
public:
    Consumer(Buffer* cbptr);
    void cons();
    bool isConsumerDead();
private:
    Buffer* BufferPtr;
};

class Producer{
public:
    Producer(Buffer* pbptr, Consumer* coptr);
    void prods();
private:
    Buffer* BufferPtr;
    Consumer* ConsumerPtr;
};

int main(){
    Buffer* tc = new Buffer();
    Consumer* cdtc = new Consumer(tc);
    Producer* pdtc = new Producer(tc,cdtc);
    std::thread t[5]; //declare an array of thread objects
    int i = 0;
    for(; i<3; ++i){
        t[i]=std::thread(&Producer::prods,std::ref(pdtc));
    }
    for(; i<5; ++i){
        t[i]=std::thread(&Consumer::cons,std::ref(cdtc));
    }

    cout << "Debug1" << endl;
    cout << "Debug1" << endl;
    cout << "Debug1" << endl;

    for(i = 0; i<5; ++i){
        t[i].join();
        cout << "now i is :" << i << endl;
    }

    cout << "All threads terminated" << endl;
    return 0;
}

void Buffer::put(){
    std::unique_lock<mutex> locker(mu); //unique_lock
    if(consumerRunTurns>=200){
            cond.notify_one();
            return;
            }
    while(isBufferFull()==1){
        if(consumerRunTurns>=200){
            cond.notify_one();
            break;
        }
        cond.wait(locker);
    }
    if(consumerRunTurns>=200){
            return;
    }
    if(isBufferFull()==0)
        cond.notify_one();
    ++count;
    std::cout << "producer thread" << this_thread::get_id() << ",count = " << count << endl;
}
int Buffer::get(){
    std::unique_lock<mutex> locker(mu); //unique_lock
    while(isBufferEmpty()==1){
        cond.wait(locker);
    }
    if(isBufferEmpty()==0)
        cond.notify_one();
    --count;
    std::cout << "consumer thread" << this_thread::get_id() << ",count = " << count << endl;
    return count;
}
bool Buffer::isBufferEmpty(){
    if(count <=0){
        std::cout << "buffer is empty, consumer thread" << this_thread::get_id() << " is about to suspend." << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
bool Buffer::isBufferFull(){
    if(count >=10){
        std::cout << "buffer is full, producer thread" << this_thread::get_id() << " is about to suspend." << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

Consumer::Consumer(Buffer* cbptr):BufferPtr(cbptr){
}

bool Consumer::isConsumerDead(){
    if(consumerRunTurns >= 200){
        cout << "consumer Dead" << endl;
        cout << "consumer Dead" << endl;
        cout << "consumer Dead" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

void Consumer::cons(){
    for(int i = 0; i<100; ++i){
        BufferPtr->get();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(60));
    }
    consumerRunTurns+=100;
}

Producer::Producer(Buffer* pbptr, Consumer* coptr):BufferPtr(pbptr), ConsumerPtr(coptr){}

void Producer::prods(){
    for(int i = 0; i<100; ++i){
        if(ConsumerPtr->isConsumerDead()){
            break;
        }
        BufferPtr->put();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(60));
    }
}
```

Previous Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>          // std::mutex, std::unique_lock
#include <condition_variable> // std::condition_variable

using namespace std;

std::mutex mu; //mutex
//std::unique_lock<mutex> locker(mu); //unique_lock
std::condition_variable cond;

std::mutex m_mutex;

class Buffer {
public:
Buffer():count(0) {}
void put();
int get();
bool isBufferEmpty();
bool isBufferFull();
private:
int count;
}; //end class Buffer

//Thread Class and Functions inside:
class Consumer{
public:
    Consumer(Buffer* cbptr);
    void cons();
    bool isConsumerDead();
private:
    Buffer* BufferPtr;
    int consumerDeadFlag;
};

class Producer{
public:
    Producer(Buffer* pbptr, Consumer* coptr);
    void prods();
private:
    Buffer* BufferPtr;
    Consumer* ConsumerPtr;
};

int main(){
    Buffer* tc = new Buffer();
    Consumer* cdtc = new Consumer(tc);
    Producer* pdtc = new Producer(tc,cdtc);
    std::thread t[5]; //declare an array of thread objects
    int i = 0;
    for(; i<3; ++i){
        t[i]=std::thread(&Producer::prods,std::ref(pdtc));
    }
    for(; i<5; ++i){
        t[i]=std::thread(&Consumer::cons,std::ref(cdtc));
    }

    cout << "Debug1" << endl;
    cout << "Debug1" << endl;
    cout << "Debug1" << endl;

    for(i = 0; i<5; ++i){
        t[i].join();
        cout << "now i is :" << i << endl;
    }

    cout << "All threads terminated" << endl;
    return 0;
}

void Buffer::put(){
    std::unique_lock<mutex> locker(mu); //unique_lock
    while(isBufferFull()==1){
        cond.wait(locker);
    }
    if(isBufferFull()==0)
        cond.notify_one();
    ++count;
    std::cout << "producer thread" << this_thread::get_id() << ",count = " << count << endl;
}
int Buffer::get(){
    std::unique_lock<mutex> locker(mu); //unique_lock
    while(isBufferEmpty()==1){
        cond.wait(locker);
    }
    if(isBufferEmpty()==0)
        cond.notify_one();
    --count;
    std::cout << "consumer thread" << this_thread::get_id() << ",count = " << count << endl;
    return count;
}
bool Buffer::isBufferEmpty(){
    if(count <=0){
        std::cout << "buffer is empty, consumer thread" << this_thread::get_id() << " is about to suspend." << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
bool Buffer::isBufferFull(){
    if(count >=10){
        std::cout << "buffer is full, producer thread" << this_thread::get_id() << " is about to suspend." << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

Consumer::Consumer(Buffer* cbptr):BufferPtr(cbptr){
    consumerDeadFlag = 0;
}

bool Consumer::isConsumerDead(){
    if(consumerDeadFlag > 1){
        cout << "consumer Dead" << endl;
        cout << "consumer Dead" << endl;
        cout << "consumer Dead" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

void Consumer::cons(){
    for(int i = 0; i<100; ++i){
        BufferPtr->get();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
    ++consumerDeadFlag;
}

Producer::Producer(Buffer* pbptr, Consumer* coptr):BufferPtr(pbptr), ConsumerPtr(coptr){}

void Producer::prods(){
    for(int i = 0; i<100; ++i){
        if(ConsumerPtr->isConsumerDead()){
            break;
        }
        BufferPtr->put();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
producer threadDebug12,count = 1
producer thread4,count = 2

producer thread3,count = 3
Debug1
Debug1
consumer thread5,count = 2
consumer thread6,count = 1
producer thread2,count = 2
consumer thread5,count = 1
producer thread4,count = 2
producer thread3,count = 3
consumer thread6,count = 2
producer thread2,count = 3
producer thread4,count = 4
producer thread3,count = 5
consumer thread5,count = 4
consumer thread6,count = 3
producer thread2,count = 4
producer thread4,count = 5
consumer thread5,count = 4
producer thread3,count = 5
consumer thread6,count = 4
producer thread2,count = 5
consumer thread5,count = 4
producer thread4,count = 5
producer thread3,count = 6
consumer thread6,count = 5
producer thread2,count = 6
producer thread4,count = 7
producer thread3,count = 8
consumer thread5,count = 7
consumer thread6,count = 6
producer thread2,count = 7
consumer thread5,count = 6
producer thread4,count = 7
producer thread3,count = 8
consumer thread6,count = 7
producer thread2,count = 8
consumer thread5,count = 7
producer thread4,count = 8
producer thread3,count = 9
consumer thread6,count = 8
producer thread2,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread2,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread2,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread2,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread2,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread2,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread2,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread2,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread2,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread2,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread2,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread2,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread2,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread2,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread2,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread2,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread2,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread2,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread2,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread2,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread2,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread2,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread2,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread2,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread2,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread2,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread2,count = 10
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread2,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread2,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread4,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
consumer thread5,count = 9
producer thread2,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread3 is about to suspend.
consumer thread6,count = 9
producer thread3,count = 10
buffer is full, producer thread4 is about to suspend.
buffer is full, producer thread2 is about to suspend.
```

etc. (due to the limit of words)

```
consumer Dead
consumer Dead
consumer Dead
```

Comment: [`std::thread::join`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) does not *kill* the thread - it waits for the thread to finish.

Comment: As said, join will make the parent thread yield until the child thread is done executing, which might mean "forever" is the child is stuck in a loop. As far as I know there is no instant stopping of child threads at all: either detach them and make sure they exit before their scope is over or code them in a way that guarantees they will eventually exit.

Comment: What happens if one or more of your producers are blocked on `BufferPtr->put();` (specifically waiting for the condition), but your consumers have both ended ? One word : deadlock.

Comment: @TheMarlboroMan, "Yield" often has a specific meaning when talking about multi-threaded code. It's probably more appropriate to say that `t.join()` _blocks_ the caller until thread `t` has terminated.  A `yield()` function typically; does nothing, waits for nothing, takes no time _unless_ other threads are RUNNABLE, but not actually RUNNING.

Comment: Note that you're producing 300 items, but only consuming 200 (and are only able to buffer 10), which is basically why you have this issue. An easy way out would be to not limit your consumers to only 100 items each, but rather keep them running for as long as there are items to be consumed (ie. until the producers have ended and the buffer is empty).

Comment: @TheMarlboroMan, Re, "detach them and make sure they exit before their scope is over." The whole point of `detach()` is that you want to allow the _thread_ to continue running even after the `std::thread` instance that created it has been destroyed. If your code can ensure that the _thread_ will end before the `thread` is destroyed, then `join()` is the right way to go. `detach()` is dangerous.

Comment: @Solomon Slow, yeah, of course. However, the OP is starting out and wanted to "kill" a thread, so a few leads were provided in plain English :). The scope thing was badly phrased, thinking of beginners' traps (references that go out of scope, memory pulled from under the feet...). In any case, I am sure the OP will benefit of all approaches (and perhaps, an answer!). Cheers :).

Comment: @Sander De Dycker Thank you for your advice. However, producing 300 items, but only consuming 200 is the task requirement. That is why I wrote a function to check if the consumer is dead. If it is, quit the producer loop.

Comment: It can only be a deadlock if you have multiple locks and multiple threads and the locks can be acquired in different orders. Solution: always acquire them in the same order. This looks more like a single resource wait to me.

Comment: Since no-one has done so yet, I've condensed my comments into an answer with a bit more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, [`std::thread::join`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) does not *kill* a thread - it waits for the thread to finish.

You have 3 producer threads (each producing 100 items), but only 2 consumer threads (each consuming 100 items). This means there's a surplus of 100 items being produced. Add to that a buffer with a capacity of only 10 items, and your **producers will never finish on their own before the consumers have finished**.

This means you need a mechanism to end the producer loops early (ie. as soon as the consumer loops have ended).

Your attempt to address this has however left you open to a **infinitely blocked thread** (similar to a deadlock, but not quite). The scenario that jumps out at me (which doesn't mean that's the only one), is when one or more producer threads are blocked on `cond.wait(locker);` (in `Buffer::put`), but all consumer threads have ended (meaning the `cond.notify_one();` in `Buffer::get` will no longer happen). Those producer thread(s) will thus wait forever, and the corresponding `join`(s) won't return.

To avoid this situation, you can consider using [`std::condition_variable::wait_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for) instead of `std::condition_variable::wait` to avoid the blocking wait. Every time the timeout happens, you have a chance to check if the consumers have ended, and end the producer thread when that's the case.

The way you check if the consumer threads have ended could also be improved. One option would be to first `join` the 2 consumer threads. When both consumer threads are joined, signal all producer threads that they should end as well, then `join` the producer threads. The signal in question could be eg. a [`std::atomic<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) that is checked in each iteration of the producer. This will work best if the `BufferPtr->put();` is changed to a `BufferPtr->try_put();`, which either inserts an item in the buffer, or returns immediately (or after a timeout if you prefer) when the buffer is full.

Note that there are more issues in your code (not least of which is that you use the same `condition_variable` to signal both "not empty" and "not full"), but they're not in the scope of this question.

Comment: That's not a deadlock. A deadlock is a circular chain of locks. That's just an unreleased lock.

Comment: @user207421 : technically, you're right. Imo it doesn't hurt thinking of it as a deadlock, since you have a thread that is blocked without a chance of getting unblocked (if it quacks like a duck ...). In any case, to avoid confusion, I've changed the terminology. Thanks for pointing it out.